# Cutting multiple lines/curves with a closed path in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, shapes, path

[image]

Let's take a bunch of lines, like in (A)
(We could have bezier curves, either. Let's say: open paths)

Let's take then a circle (or another closed path), like (B)

Let's put the each above/below the other(s) like (C)

Is there in Inkscape a (quick) way to get (D) or (E) NOT just as the result of a CLIPPING MASK, but as a set of inscribed(D)/outscribed(E) paths?

I mean: paths beginning/ending where the circle happened to "trim" the rest.

Thank You

Comment: Could be interesting: [https://inkscape.org/sk/~Moini/%E2%98%85multi-bool-extension-cut-difference-division](https://inkscape.org/sk/~Moini/%E2%98%85multi-bool-extension-cut-difference-division)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from a bunch of lines, you can [combine](http://inkscape.org/doc/advanced/tutorial-advanced.html) them with **Ctrl+K** (refer to *Path* menu):

[image: Combined lines]

Then you have to put the second path in the desired position:

[image: Both the paths]

Now, you can [cut](http://inkscape.org/doc/advanced/tutorial-advanced.html) the path with **Ctrl+Alt+/**:

[image: after cutting]

Here come the boring part: each line is cutted in two or more segments. You have to select them one by one (I have colored the stroke while selecting, just to see the selected paths):

[image: Selected paths]

You can move the selection and the work is done:

[image: Work is done]

Note that the selection is made by single paths, you can combine or group them to simplify further operations.

Comment: This loses style information? I have 8 stacked paths with different styles.

Comment: Combining operation results in a single path with a single style (the style of the first path). In order to maintain 8 path with different styles you should either applying the method separately to each path or you should use a [clipping mask](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clip.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer here: [Cut Multiple Objects](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65104/how-do-we-cut-multiple-objects-with-multiple-colors-at-the-edge-of-a-shape-with) with the "Mulit-Bool" add-on.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/110193)