# How do we cut multiple objects with multiple colors at the edge of a shape? Without clipping!

Tags: inkscape

I got a similar problem as this post:
[This Post ;-)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64892/make-words-art-i-inkscape-how-can-i-cut-the-words-that-is-out-of-the-shape/64903#64903)
And the difference is i've got multiple objects (actually paths) with different colors. Also, i want to know if i can do this without clipping, 'cause clipping creates an object that cannot be converted to a path, which adds a lot of limitations. Please look at [[this post]](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64870/convert-clipped-item-into-normal-path-in-inkscape/64878?noredirect=1#comment97622_64878) for further info: So, once again, how can i cut the objects that is out of the model shape （which is colored in purple in the image below）, or we say, cut them at the edge.
So here are those objects with different colors:

[image: objects with different colors]

And the purple box is the model object,

[image: the purple square model box]

and i want those circles to disappear at the edge of the purple square, so i can get a square filled with colorful circles!

And i create an example with gimp (which creates bitmaps) and show you what is the thing i exactly i want:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the [division](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Combining.html) operator and delete the undesired paths?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [How do I clip parts of my Inkscape diagram such that its corners are perfectly rectangular?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/45614/19174)

Comment: division not really works :-( It seems doing nothing.   And as i said in the question, clipping will create an object that is "unpathable" which brings lots of limitations.

Comment: Division works on **exactly** two paths, not on a bunch of paths. You should **combine** your circles, draw your rectangle, select rectangle and circles and apply division (or **intersection**). After this, you can **break apart** your path and fill the circles.

Comment: But combining paths make them the same color, which is not what i want...... So, can you solve this?

Comment: As I said, you need to fill the circles. For example, you can leave the original image in a locked layer after duplicating it (Ctrl-D) and moving the copy in another layer. After the break apart, remove the fill, so you can see the colors on the original image and you can pick them with the eyedropper and use them to fill the pieces of circles. Try, please, I have no time at the moment to write a decent answer. Or see the suggestion of Wrzlprmft. Should the final image be a SVG or a PNG?

Comment: This question may be a possible duplicate to this http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/47180/inkscape-how-to-cut-a-group 
There isn't a perfect solution, however if you follow the link in my answer, there is an unofficial extension provided. All the best @user56336

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the [Multi-Bool](https://inkscape.org/en/~Moini/%E2%98%85multi-bool-extension-cut-difference-division) addon (download by clicking on the arrow `↓` right of the headline).

Install the plugin as described on the linked site. Restart Inkscape.

1. Completely ungroup all circles.
2. Select everything (circles and rectangle).
3. Click `Extensions > Boolean > Multiple Division`.
   (In contrast to Inkscapes native boolean functions, this does not remove the rectangle on the top. You may remove the rectangle manually.)
4. Select the outer parts of the circles and remove them.

[image: multi-bool the hard way]

Selecting the outer parts is actually more work than one expects. But there is an easy way around this: Use the negation of the rectangle and multi-difference.

1. Draw a rectangle over the complete canvas.
2. Place your original rectangle on top of it.
3. Select both rectangles.
4. Subtract (`Path > Difference` or `ctrl+-`).
5. Select everything (circles and negated rectangle).
6. Click `Extensions > Boolean > Multiple Difference`.

[image: multi-bool the easy way]

Comment: Link is broken. [This](https://gitlab.com/moini_ink/inx-pathops) appears to be the most recent incarnation, though I am unsure if the actions in this answer transfer across verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

The multi-bool library linked by @Socowi has been deprecated by the author and removed. The current version is at:

- https://gitlab.com/moini_ink/inx-patho (Inkscape versions over 1.0)
- https://gitlab.com/su-v/inx-pathops (Inkscape versions before 1.0)

Comment: It appears the repo for >1.0 is also not reachable anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is reachable! But unfortunately there is a typo in the link and the last two letters are missing. The correct link is

https://gitlab.com/moini_ink/inx-pathops

I have tried it with version 1.0.1 and works as expected.